# Откуда взялись странные символы в ответе сервера?

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, socket.io

```js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://tradethatskin.com');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('connected to tradethatskin.com');
  socket.emit('get pricelist');
});

socket.on('pricelist', function(prices) {
  console.log(prices);
});
```

Код выше должен возвращать JSON c названием и ценой.

Что то типа такого:

```js
...
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Freehand (Minimal Wear) : -212.97
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Freehand (Well-Worn) : -153.98
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Gamma Doppler (Factory New) : -515.84
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Gamma Doppler (Minimal Wear) : -551.51
★ StatTrak™ Bayonet | Lore (Battle-Scarred) : -186.71
...
```

Но вместо этого я получаю:

```js
...
â StatTrakâ¢ Bayonet | Freehand (Minimal Wear) : -212.97
â StatTrakâ¢ Bayonet | Freehand (Well-Worn) : -153.98
â StatTrakâ¢ Bayonet | Gamma Doppler (Factory New) : -515.84
â StatTrakâ¢ Bayonet | Gamma Doppler (Minimal Wear) : -551.51
â StatTrakâ¢ Bayonet | Lore (Battle-Scarred) : -186.71
...
```

Я понимаю что тут проблема с кодировкой, но как ее решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  var socket = io('https://tradethatskin.com');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('get pricelist');
});
socket.on('pricelist', function(prices) {
  console.log(prices);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Нужно в настройках сервера изменить отображение UTF символов. Если сервер не ваш, вам стоит либо смириться, либо обрабатывать каждый `item`. Я написал пример, но нужно доработать регулярку. К вашему и моему сожалению я не особо разбираюсь в регулярках. Тем не менее вопрос был не в этом. Обрабатывается вроде быстро.

```
var server = require('http').createServer();

var socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://tradethatskin.com');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('get pricelist');
});

socket.on('pricelist', function(prices) {
    var data = [];
    Object.keys(prices).forEach(function (currentValue) {
        if(currentValue.indexOf('â') > -1 === true) {
            data.push(currentValue.replace('â', '★'))
        } else {
            data.push(currentValue)
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
});
server.listen(3080);
```

Примерно вот так отдает консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверено для клиента в Chrome 63.0.3239.132, Firefox 57.0.4, Edge 41.16299.15.0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но сервер то не мой) Я пытаюсь получить данные из сайта https://tradethatskin.com

Comment: Я ответ плюсагул, но считаю, что ответ должен быть более развернутым....  Твой ответ больше на коммент похож...

Comment: @Puvvl а если Вы про мой сервер говорите, то такая проблема только с этим сайтом https://tradethatskin.com
Я получал такие же данные с других сайтов и все символы отображались нармально

Comment: @Puvvl Код, который Вы написали у меня тоже нормально работает, но  он работает только если его использовать на html странице.
А мне нужно чтобы он работал на сервере. Я тестирую скрипт не через браузер, а в терминале `node server.js`

Comment: @MikeReacher данные с сайта tradethatskin.com приходят нормально, ищите проблему у вас на сервере. Вы сами можете наблюдать в каком виде приходят данные клиенту.

Comment: @Puvvl но Вы же тестировали код в браузере. Он же не будет работать на сервере. Или я что то неправильно понимаю?
И я тестировал этот код с другими сайтами, и данные отображались нормально.
`var socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://другой аналогичный сайт');`
В этом случае аналогичные данные отображались нормально, значит проблема не в моем сервере.

Comment: @Puvvl у меня в браузере тоже все отлично отображается

Comment: @MikeReacher, завтра я попробую протестить у себя на сервере, сейчас такой возможности нету, завтра дам более конструктивный ответ.

Comment: @Puvvl благодарю за помощь, а то я уже второй день мучаюсь

Comment: @Puvvl для справки: запускал на ноде в своём линуксе - проблема правда есть, в объекте хранятся битые строки (а в браузере норм)

Comment: @MikeReacher, вы были правы, сервер действительно отправляет нам не те символы, я дополнил ответ, надеюсь вам помог.

Comment: @Puvvl большое спасибо за помощь, но почему тогда в браузере все норм?